# HOW to call to angularjs method from a jsf commandbutton

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsf, jsf-2

Does anyone know if you can call an angularjs method from a `jsf` `commandButton`. A button like this:

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{taskController.stopAllTasks}"
    ng-click="deActivateTasks()"
    styleClass="btn btn-default"
    value="Reset To Idle"">
</h:commandButton>
```

I tried using the `ng-click` but the `deActivateTasks()` method is not called and no error is recorded either.

I can call `deActivateTasks()` from non `JSF` tags so I know the method is accessible. I need to be able to execute the action `taskController.stopAllTasks` and call the angular method.

Comment: why are you trying to mix event listeners like this?

Comment: I have not tried it but you could use a pass-through attribute for that to be achieved.